# How to display terminals with commands on startup

Tags: bash, autostart, startup-applications, i3-wm

I'm trying to open 2 terminals on startup. One will execute one command, and the other one will execute a different command.

I already tried using Ubuntu's Startup Applications program pointing to scripts that only executed these commands. They were executable and worked fine but this didn't work for opening them on startup. I also tried creating systemd services for them, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? Also, if I'm using i3 will the screen split automatically with these terminals?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a terminal command open in a terminal, specify "Terminal=true" in the desktop file, for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Top
Exec=top
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

This will open `top` in your default terminal emulator. Once you quit `top`, the terminal will close.

If you want to leave the terminal open when the command you run finishes, then you can call `bash` after it, as in:

```
Exec=sh -c 'ls ; bash'
```

This will run the `ls` command, then give you a terminal prompt.

Place the `.desktop` file in the `.config/autostart` folder to have it run automatically when you log in.

Comment: Thanks! Should the .desktop file be located at ~/.local/share/applications/? Do i need to do anything else after?

Comment: I added a sentence on where to put the launcher in order to have it autostart.